# Receive notification back from Xamarin Forms Maps

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app that, during it's execution, launches the Maps plugin (from the `Essentials` package).  Here's the code that I use to launch the maps:

```
var location = new Location(latitude, longitude);
var options = new MapLaunchOptions 
{ 
    NavigationMode = NavigationMode.Driving
};

await Map.OpenAsync(location, options);
```

However, since I want the user to be directed to a location, I want to know when they get there; the idea being that some events occur within the app when the user arrives.

It looks, to me, like the Maps plug-in doesn't provide any kind of notification. 
 I've been through a few iterations of this.  Initially, I thought of using the Geolocator to identify when the user arrives, then had a look at a [Geofencing](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/GeofencePlugin) plug-in that I found.

Before I head down either of these rabbit holes: is it possible to get the Maps plug-in to tell me when the user arrives at a location.

Comment: the plugin is just a helper that launches the system Maps app.  There is no way I know of to get notification back from another app like that.  If you need this feature you probably need to embed the map control within your app

Comment: No, Maps is not a "plugin", it is using an existing app on the user's device, be it Apple Maps, Google Maps, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It is **possible** by [Creating the Custom Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin#creating-the-custom-map) to realize it in each platform.

You can create a [Timer](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-timer/) Task in [Background service](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-background-tasks/) to execute getting current location from [Geolocator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?tabs=android#using-geolocation) (not a plugin).Then when current location is detination , message can be passed to where you want to do.

By the way , about native framework in each platform . There are some methods like `UpdateLocation` can be directly used to know the current location .

Such as :

**IOS** has [**startUpdatingLocation**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423750-startupdatinglocation?language=objc) method to listen the current location.

**Android** has **[onLocationChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged(android.location.Location))** method to know the current location if changed.

What need to do is to notification the user he has arrived the detination when the current position enters the range .

Comment: Thanks for this - this is very useful.  Can I just clarify one thing, though - am I right in thinking that you're advocating a custom map because that makes it possible to embed a map in the application?

Comment: @PaulMichaels No, forms map also can realize it in app.The role of custom map is to reflect other powerful features of the platform map, including the custom design of the interface or the native function of the map.